# Where are all of hard linked files located?

Tags: macos, unix, inode, file-attributes

When we create a directory `mkdir foo`, initially the number of hard links is 2 `ls -ld foo` -because of the directory itself and the shortcut dot `.` inside that directory. If we create a new directory inside that foo, the number of hard links for foo increases -because of the parent directory's shortcut `..` inside new directory. So the number of hard links for foo should be 1+1+number of directories inside foo. In Ubuntu there is no problem, but in Mac OS X, for some directories (let's say `~/Documents`) this formula for total number of hard links does not work. Usually the number of hard links is bigger than `1+1+number of directories inside Documents`. When I try to find files by using that directory's idone by using `find / -inum inumofDocuments -print` it only returns Documents. So I wonder where are the other files with that inode number are located?

Comment: Just a guess - have you tried looking in `NSURL`? `NSURL` can keep track of a file/directory it doesn't matter if you move it to any other place or rename it. may be its keeping hard links to the actual file/directory. BTW in `Finder` the favorites are `NSURL`s.

Comment: one more point - if you delete some items from `Documents` it will move them the trash and those folders will still have a hardlink to `Documents` folder

Comment: finding the path based on Inode isn't easy... but worrying about the link count is like worrying About refcount

Comment: For some reason in OSX, a file increments the hardlink counter:
mkdir testdir; cd testdir; ls -la; touch blah; ls -la.  You will see that adding the file blah makes the number of hardlinks to '.' go from 2 -> 3.  This is osx specific because this is not the case in Ubuntu/RHEL.

Comment: Thanks @jshort I had not paid attention to that. Obviously I did not expect regular files to increase number of hard links, but in OS X they do...